# What does <a href="/"> do?

Tags: html

I would like to know what the following HTML code snippet does:

```
 <a href="/"><img src="cat.png"></a>
```

What does the `/` value for the `href` attribute refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "/" refers to the root of your application for example  `<a href ="/"><img src="cat.png"></a>` would redirect to `www.example.com`, `<a href ="/about"><img src="cat.png"></a>` would redirect to `www.example.com/about`.